# Task Manager greyed out only for some users

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, task-manager

On a Windows Server 2012 R2 system joined to a domain, the Task Manager is greyed out from the right-click menu from the task bar, but only for some users. Nothing is explicitly set in Group Policy and I cannot find anything in the Local Policy which may be causing this.
Internet searches are only showing this problem when it's affecting all users, I can't seem to find anything where only some users are affected.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: Greyed out when right clicking the start menu?

Comment: What happens if you press CTRL-ALT-DEL? And if you explicitly run taskmgr.exe?